# how to store value till it not submit

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I have 3 pages:

1. Register.php
2. Success.php
3. Login.php

Now when my user register the it's values validate on success.php and if not correct it returned on register page and if it get correct then it gone to login page. I want when it comes back to register page when values not correct then values which was filled before submit should remain as it.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: use `session variables` - when the first form is submitted set a session variable like `$_SESSION['register']=$_POST;` if there is a problem and the user has to be returned to `register.php` then use the values in `$_SESSION['register']` to re-populate the form fields

Comment: I did same which u said but when it returned to false it show me error of Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0015686200{main}( )..\register.php:0 " /

Comment: <form data-toggle="validator" novalidate="" action="success.php" method="post"><div class="form-group valid-form"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="namefeild_name" placeholder="Full Name *"required="" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['namefeild_name'];?>" /><span class="help-block with-errors">Please enter your Full name</span></div><div class="form-group"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary" name="reg">Register</button></div></form>

Comment: Do not put requested additional information into comments (especially not code). Instead, please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by just returning the values the user sent in. Using $_GET
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Just take the paramaters the users sent in and pass them back in the url.

Like if failed, return to url:

```
register.php?uname=value1&email=value2
```

Then in register.php get the paramaters with

```
$username = $_GET['uname'];
```

Then echo it out in the form again as value:

```
<input id="uname" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['uname']){
                   echo $username;
                   }
                   else{echo "enter username";} ?>" />
```

Very simple example here, but just follow w3school and you should have everything you need to get this done.

Comment: Passing parameters via URL is not a good option, as he has register form so he will be asking password as well. Do you think sending password to URL is a good option? The information must be sent using POST method! please improve your PHP!

Comment: The return can be sent as GET, I never said you should post the registrationform with GET. You never return the password. But yeah, I concure. It should be done with sessions really.

Comment: To keep things simple and secure the best approach is sessions so there will not be any chances of losing data. We can use GET where information is not sensitive, but some GET + SESSION same time is not a professional approach in this case. So SESSION will work in this case.

Comment: I tried, but since I registered today I didnt have enough "points".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JavaScript's [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). (or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage))

With that you will be able to store information between pages. Then just pass all the information at the same time as POST data on the last page.

**Example:**

```
var existing = localStorage.getItem('user_name');
if (existing == null) {
    // The user has not set their name, lets assume it's John Doe
    existing = 'John Doe';
    localStorage.setItem('user_name', existing);
} 
alert('Hello ' + existing + '!');
```

---

Alternatively, on the pure PHP side of things, you could also use [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php). This way all the information stays on the server instead of in the user's browser.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
    $_SESSION['count']++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using PHP, so best option is to use SESSIONS.

You can create something like:

```
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
```

Than these values can be used in the 3 pages for processing. 
Your first page is register.php, so in the beginning of page just add a php function `session_destroy();` so that when user open page any live session will be destroyed and new session will be started with that specific user. Also don't forget to start sessions by using function `session_start();` on every page. I hope this will solve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method, IMO, using PHP would be to use a `session variable` which holds the values of all POSTed data from `register.php`

A simple function can be called to retrieve the value from the session variable and consequently displayed in the HTML form fields. This is an example of how you could achieve the desired result.

```
<?php

    /* success.php */
    session_start();


    function getvalue( $var='register', $field=false ){
        if( isset( $_SESSION[ $var ] ) ){
            return array_key_exists( $field, $_SESSION[ $var ] ) ? $_SESSION[ $var ][ $field ] : '';
        }
        return '';
    }


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /* 
           a boolean to indicate if everything is OK with the submitted
           data - to be updated later according to your rules
        */
        $ok=false;



        /* set the session variable */
        $_SESSION['register']=$_POST;



        /* process POST data - set value of $ok to true if everything is OK! */
        /*
            this is where you determine the rules for success or failure
        */


        /* Determine where the use goes next */
        if( $ok ){
            exit( header('Location: login.php') );
        } else {
            exit( header('Location: register.php') );
        }


    }
?>



<?php
    /* register.php */
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>register.php</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--
            the form fields should initially be blank, but if the user is redirected 
            back to the page the fields should show the values stored in the 
            session variable.

        -->
        <form name='register' method='post' action='success.php'>
            <!-- various form fields - example -->
            <input type='text' name='email' value='<?php echo getvalue('register','email'); ?>' />
            <input type='text' name='username' value='<?php echo getvalue('register','username'); ?>' />
            <!-- more fields -->

            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using the listed below code on success.php.     Kindly correct me where m wrong.

Comment: i apply this but not working. Can you please explain this to me more.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['namefeild_name'] = $_POST['namefeild_name'];
$_SESSION['mob'] = $_POST['mob'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['city'] = $_POST['city'];



if(isset($_POST['reg']))
{
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)       {   die('Could Not Connect: '.mysql_error());   }
mysql_select_db("database", $con);

if(!isset($_POST['namefeild_name']) || 

        !isset($_POST['mob']) ||

        !isset($_POST['pass']) ||

        !isset($_POST['pas']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['city'])) 
    {

        die("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.')</script>");       

    }
    $uid = $_POST['namefeild_name']; // required

    $name = $_POST['namefeild_name']; // required

    $uname=$_POST['mob'];   //required

    $pass=$_POST['pass'];   //required

    $pas=$_POST['pas'];     //required

    $email = $_POST['email']; // required

    $city = $_POST['city'];     // not required

    $type = 'BAL';  // not required



    $id=md5($uname);

 $error_message = "";

    $string_exp = "/\b([A-Za-z]{1,30}[- ]{0,1}|[A-Za-z]{1,30}[- \']{1}  
    [A-Za-z]{1,30}[- ]{0,1}|[A-Za-z]{1,2}[ -\']{1}[A-Za-z]{1,30}){2,5}/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {

    $error_message .= "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Name does not appear to be valid.')</script>";
    header('location:register.php?errorname');
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$uname)) {

    $error_message .= "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Mobile Number does not appear to be valid.')</script>";
    header('location:register.php?errormob');
  } 

    $string_exp = "/\b([A-Za-z]{1,30}[- ]{0,1}){1}/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$pas)) {

    $error_message .= "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The password you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />Contain Atleast one Uppercase Letter<br />Contain atleast one lower case letter<br />contain atleast one number')</script>";
    header('location:register.php?errorpass');
  }


    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$city)) {

    $error_message .= "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('City does not appear to be valid.')</script>";
    header('location:register.php?errorcity');
  }

  if(strlen($city) < 2) {

    $error_message .= "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('City does not appear to be valid.')</script>";
    header('location:register.php?errorcity');

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    die($error_message);

  }



else
{
    $query=mysql_query("select * from customer where uname='".$uname."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $res=mysql_fetch_row($query);
    if($res)
    {
        header("location: register.php?useralreadyexits");
        session_destroy();                     
    }
    elseif(!$res)
    {
        $datetime=Date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
        $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer VALUES('$id','$uname','$name','$pas','$email','$city','$datetime');");
        $result2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO payment VALUES('$id','$uname','25','$datetime','$type');");
        if($result && $result2)     
        {   
            header("location: login.php?success");
            session_destroy();
        }
        else            
        {   
            $_SESSION['name']=$uname;
            header('location:register.php?notregistered');
        }   
    }
}
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```